# PowerShell escape single quote in the input value from file

Tags: powershell

By reading the Email address from the file, querying user status in Active directory. It works if email address didn't have single quote in it. If files has Email address with quote  like `user's@example.com`, PowerShell giving below error message.

How to escape single quote in PowerShell?

**Code**

```
Import-Csv users.csv| 
ForEach-Object{
    
    $UserStatus=Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($_.Email)'" -properties "*"| select -Expand userAccountControl    
$_ |
Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "starts" -Value $UserStatus -PassThru
}  |
export-csv added-filed.csv
```

**Error message**

```
Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'EmailAddress -eq 'user's@example.com'' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '21'.
At added-active-status.ps1:4 char:17
+ ... $UserStatus=Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($_.Email)'" -prop ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Comment: I wonder how does `-LDAPFilter` resolves this, never seen an email address with single quotes, beyond my mind how is this allowed in any Company. What happens if you try `-LDAPFilter "(emailAddress=$($_.Email))"` ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thanks LDAP filter worked for me `Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "EmailAddress -eq '$($_.Email)'" -properties "*"` like this.

Comment: That's good to know! You should use [LDAP Syntax](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) when using `-LDAPFiter` like I did in my comment. In my experience should also be faster than using the normal `-Filter`. i.e.: `-LDAPFilter "(emailAddress=user's@example.com)"` should be resolved without errors.

Comment: imm. that didn't work. I end up using this syntax. `Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq `"$email`"" -properties "*"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this were about *PowerShell's* escaping rules, you'd have to *double* embedded `'` chars. inside a `'...'` string: `-Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($_.Email -replace "'", "''")'"`

However, given that it is the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet (its underlying provider) that interprets the content of the `-Filter` argument, it is probably safer to switch to using embedded `"..."` quoting, in which case any `'` chars. in the value of `$_.Email` do not require escaping (the assumption is that `$_.Email` doesn't also have embedded `"` characters):

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq `"$($_.Email)`""
```

Comment: Ohhhhhhh. Fancy, fancy. Good to know!(:

Comment: Thanks, @AbrahamZinala, but note that I was only speculating about doubled `'` not working - I cannot personally verify that. If _you_ can, do let us know. Either way, the use of embedded `"..."` quoting simplifies the solution.

Comment: Only if i was at work, but even then, we don't have users with quotes in their emails.

Comment: I wonder how does `-LDAPFilter` resolves this, I agree @AbrahamZinala, beyond my mind how any Company would allow single quotes in an email address....

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to escape a single quote, with another. Give this a try:

```
Import-Csv users.csv | 
    ForEach-Object -Process {
        
        $Email = $_.Email.Split('''') -join "''"

        $UserStatus = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq $Email" -properties "*"| select -Expand userAccountControl    
        $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "starts" -Value $UserStatus -PassThru

    } | export-csv added-filed.csv
```